# how to add multiple ethernet mac interfaces in u-boot

Tags: ethernet, u-boot, uclinux

I am new with u-boot and uclinux ,

How can i add one more ethernet mac interface in u-boot.
As seen at startup of u-boot in only one interface comes
Net:   eth driver init
M2S_MAC

I want two add one more so that i can have one more ip address i.e. eth1

I have read following question

> [Can u-boot support more than one ethernet port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747239/can-u-boot-support-more-than-one-ethernet-port)

where i got that eth_current_changed() and eth_set_current() in net/eth.c has to change

but it doesn't defines ,how to add a interface . i have got the driver for the new mac interface also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple ethernet devices are well supported.  The exact details will depend on what board you're working from and the driver in question, or if you're trying to have different distinct drivers registered.

Comment: there are two different drivers @TomRini

Comment: Then you can look at board/ti/am335x/board.c as that calls two different drivers in board_eth_init().